# How to get results from another table column in a row-result?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Locations : [(from, to) (1, 2), (2, 3)]

Stations: [(id, name) (1, South end), (2, North end), (3, Central end)]

I want my output to be like:

Output table: [(from, to) (South end, North end), (North end, Central end)]

I have tried the following query.

```
select status_step.id, from_step , to_step, status_step.name,
direction from timings inner join stations
on timings.from_id= stations.id GROUP BY stations.id;
```

However, it doesnt give me the intended answer. Any hint/ help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join only once with something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t.from = s.id THEN s.name END) as `from`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.to = s.id THEN s.name END) as `to`
FROM stations s
JOIN timings t
 ON(s.id IN(t.from,t.to))
GROUP BY t.from,t.to
```

If `only_full_group_by` is enabled, then add `t.from,t.to` to the selected columns.